# Existence of $x\in \mathfrak m \setminus \mathfrak m^2$ such that $xR$ is a prime ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local domain of dimension at least $2$.
Then, must there exist $x\in \mathfrak m \setminus \mathfrak m^2$ such that $xR$ is a prime ideal of $R$? What if we also assume $R$ is normal?

My thoughts: If $R$ is a UFD, then every height $1$ prime ideal is principal, and in that case the problem boils down to finding a height $1$ prime ideal not contained in $\mathfrak m^2$, can this be always done? Outside the UFD case, I have no idea.

Please help.

Comment: Why the downvote :( ?

Comment: You should at least look at Flenner's  local Bertini theorem.

Comment: The UFD case is more elementary: Pick any $x \in \mathfrak{m} \setminus \mathfrak{m}^2$. Necessarily $x$ isn't a unit. $x$ has a prime factor $p$. Necessarily $p \in \mathfrak{m} \setminus \mathfrak{m}^2$.

Comment: +1 for this question